# Is it possible to release Object in Teamcenter throgh RAC?

Tags: itk

I wanted to copy the release status of Iream revision and paste it to their dataset.This whole process I can done via ITK but I wants it to be done by RAC.

Could you pls help me out .

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setReleaseStatus(){
        WorkflowService serviceWF = WorkflowService.getService(session);

         ReleaseStatusInput relStInput = new com.teamcenter.services.rac.workflow._2007_06.Workflow.ReleaseStatusInput();
         relStInput.objects = new TCComponent[]{subLine};


          ReleaseStatusOption relStOptions = new com.teamcenter.services.rac.workflow._2007_06.Workflow.ReleaseStatusOption();
         /* // if we want delete TCReleased
          relStOptions.existingreleaseStatusTypeName = "TCReleased";
          relStOptions.newReleaseStatusTypeName = "";
          relStOptions.operation = "Delete"; // or Append or Replace
*/        
          // if we want set status TCReleased
          relStOptions.existingreleaseStatusTypeName = "";
          relStOptions.newReleaseStatusTypeName = "TCReleased";
          relStOptions.operation = "Append";

          relStInput.operations = new Workflow.ReleaseStatusOption[]{relStOptions};

          try {
            serviceWF.setReleaseStatus(new Workflow.ReleaseStatusInput[]{relStInput});
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks .Apart from workflow process API Is there any way to achieve release object through RAC ?